# Eligibility Criteria for Rolling Venice Card

Tags: public-transport, europe, italy, italian-citizens, venice

According to this site: https://www.veneziaunica.it/en/content/rolling-venice

people betwween ages of 6 and 29 can buy a Rolling Venice card, which is valid for 72 hours. On the website, I don't see any specific eligibility criteria. Can all tourists lying within that age bracket (coming from outside EU) also use this offer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're worried that there are additional secret eligibility criteria, but: Yes.